# Am I allowed to use WebSockets to refresh data realtime using WebSockets on AdSense?

Tags: websocket, adsense

I have an application using AdSense and it came to my understanding that polling is not allowed due to AdSense policies. I wonder if I use WebSockets and the server sends new data to the client when it is being created and on client I show the new data, will I violate AdSense policies?

Scenario:

I have a social-network where one can go to home feed and inbox pages. On these pages I would like to refresh data with new feed items/inbox items whenever they are inserted real-time, so the user opens the page and whenever at another end related data is generated, I would like to add the new data to the top of the page. I wonder whether this is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the official AdSense docs](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en&ref_topic=1271508&visit_id=1-636167313860277833-4040772420&rd=1#Auto-refreshing_ads):

> Publishers are not permitted to refresh a page or an element of a page without the user requesting a refresh

Additionally, [this section says](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en&ref_topic=1271508&visit_id=1-636167313860277833-4040772420&rd=1#Dynamic):

> Publishers may not place Google ads on pages where dynamic content (e.g., live chats, instant messaging, auto-refreshing comments, etc.) is the primary focus of the page.

You may even be disallowed to place AdSense ads there at all, since the items are on of the primary features on your page. To be more precise, I would need to have more information how exactly your page works, but what I can definitely say is that you are not permitted to refresh the ads with websockets, even if it would be directly connected to a user action.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do not intend to refresh the ads. I want to display the very same ads, but would like to be able to display new content, unrelated to AdSense ads. If the user views his inbox, for example and a message is received, then to show the message and to refresh the count at the inbox. This would increase the UX of the page and would not gather more profit from AdSense, since no ad refresh is involved. As a matter of fact, it reduces profit from the way users interact with the site, since they do not have to refresh the page to see new content.

Comment: The idea is to increase significantly the UX which would draw new users. That would lead to new users appearing and more page loads due to popularity, but would decrease the number of page load/user due to better data management. From your quotes it seems that this is illegal as well, probably due to AdSense's fear that ads would be refreshed as well. But that is not the case here.

Comment: If this could be safe for AdSense, that is, I can calmly refresh non-ad content because AdSense would detect ad refreshes, then the pages using AdSense could become better, drawing in more users and better selling for AdSense as well. Not to mention the fact that if the user does not have to reload the page, then he/she will stare for the same single ad for more time, which would increase the value of the ad as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think I got that wrong. One question: What happens if you click on an item? Does it open on the same page or does it force a new reload?

Comment: I am about to accept your answer if you can confirm or deny the following statement: "WebSocket refresh on content unrelated to AdSense ads is unacceptable to AdSense policies". In our case the user does not request content refresh per se, but would be a happier user and the product using AdSense could become better overall.

Comment: Clicking on a question/answer on the page will not result in actions. There are links in the items where, if the user clicks on the link, he is directed to a detail page of the question/answer where comments are shown as well and there are AdSense ads. It is highly unprobable that a user would click on an AdSense ad accidentally, as the links are many pixels away from the ad.

Comment: Spontaneously I would still say that it is not allowed, because as you describe it as auto-refreshing and it seems like a primary feature. If the click on an item happens on the same page too, I definitely would say that it is a page with dynamic content. If a click on an item forces a complete page reload, I don't think anyone can answer you this except the AdSense support. You can contact them when you earn more than 100€ (or your currency equivalent) per month.

Comment: I should mention that in some versions a notification feature exists (which refreshes only on page load right now, but could refresh via WebSockets). Those are far from the ads as well, but a notification item is clickable and leads to another page.

Comment: That limit of 100 is surpassed in a short period of time, so my client will have no problem in connecting them. I will do that and come back with information. You are correct in pointing out it is a primary feature and it will be dynamic if I introduce WebSockets. Introducing them would take time and from my client's point of view, money, so I have to make sure that there is a point in doing this to keep a clear conscience. I cannot accept your answer yet, since things are still open, but I hope I will be able to add some useful comments here in the near-future.

Comment: Of course. As I said, it really seems like an edge case since your using both dynamic elements and usual navigation elements. Keep me up to date what the support says.